# Interesting Tab and Questions-->newest Tab

Tags: support, bug

Sometimes when I visit the stack overflow site, its shows the "interesting" Tab, but sometimes it shows the "Questions-->newest" Tab. Why is it navigation not always the same? Is it a bug?

Comment: But by default the "interesting" Tab is not appear.It came only in some cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interesting` tab and the `questions -> newest` tab are two different URLs:

- Interesting is the default page for https://stackoverflow.com/
- Questions -> Newest is the default for https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Both URLs can show you a different tab next time you visit, too, as SO remembers what tab on that URL you last visited. For example, the homepage has `featured`, `hot`, `week` and `month` tabs too, and question pages have `featured`, `faq`, `votes`, `active` and `unanswered` flavours available.

Double-check your browser location, perhaps your browser auto-completed to the `/questions` URL for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.One quick question.Once we select http://stackoverflow.com/questions url is there is any link to navigate "interesting" tab?

Comment: Click the Stack Overflow logo to get back to the homepage.